# How do I create a document on firestore for a user on load? Currently, a document is only created onClick, but how do i create with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

[image: data structure]I am trying to make a collection of items. A mapped document is created on click after a user logs in, and if the user has already created a document then there are no errors. However, a new user does not yet have a document and the useEffect function is returning undefined when I look for the document. How do I create it on load for a new user?
Following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ingredients')
> I am trying to create an ingredients array.

```
   useEffect(() => {
     onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
       if (user) {
         const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
         const docRef = doc(db, "users", uid);

         //loads the user's ingredients from firebase upon login
         const getUsers = async () => {
           const data = await getDoc(docRef);
           if(data.data().ingredients != undefined){
              setImgArr(data.data().ingredients);
           }

[![Data structure][1]][1]
           else {
             await setDoc(docRef, {
               ingredients: arrayUnion({ name: "form", image: "newImg.image" }),
             });
           }
         };
         getUsers();
       } else {
         //clear the ingredients array upon logout
         setImgArr([]);
       }
     });
   }, [auth]);

  const clickHandler = async (e) => {
    try {
      setForm(e.target.value);
      //get response from edamam api
      const newImg = await getResponse();
      //redefining uid and docRef because unable to figure out how to make them global
      const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
      const docRef = doc(db, "users", uid);
      //updates firebase with new ingredient
      await updateDoc(docRef, {
        ingredients: arrayUnion({ name: form, image: newImg.image }),
      });
      setImgArr([...imgArr, newImg]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
```